# Explanation of a function

Tags: c

Could anyone can tell what the following code does?  Does it write or read on a table ? This is a function in program. I am trying to understand the program.If anyone reply with explanation it will be great help.

```
typedef struct {
  short a[16];
} PRE25G;

PRE25G pre25g_g[4] = {
    1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,           /*1*/
    1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,           /*2*/
    1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,           /*3*/
    1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,0            /*4*/
};
```

Comment: It initializes an array of four `PRE256` structures.

Comment: I don't see any function here.

Comment: In future, please don't include massive blocks of comments, especially with extraneous blank lines in between each comment line.  They provide no useful information in a question like this — they simply get in the way.

Answer (score 3):

This is not a function. The first part is a `typedef` that defines a [structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Struct_(C_programming_language)). And the latter is the definition of an initialized array of the structure type `PRE25G`.